# Mapped averaging from 2D to higher dimensional numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have some 2D numpy data that I want to translate to a higher dimensional array using a mapped average (or some other statistic).

The source data is 2D with a MxN shape, and I want to map this onto a 4D array (AxBxCxD shape).  The indicies mapping from the source data to each of the four dimensions are created from either 2D (MxN shaped) variables or tiled 1D (Mx1 shaped) variables.

Below is an a working example of what I am trying to do.  Although this seems to work, I would like to know if there is a function that would allow me to:

1)  do-away with the for-loops and

2) allow for a variable number of dimensions (3D, 4D, 5D, etc) for the destination array(s).

```
import numpy as np

# create data I want to conditionally average  (MxN array)
zz = np.random.rand(100,10)

# create variables used to define binning for conditional averaging 
# each variable defines one dimension of the final 4 dimensional array
aa = np.random.rand(100,10)*10
bb = np.random.rand(100,1) + 5
cc = np.random.rand(100,1) * 25
dd = np.random.rand(100,1)* 50 + 100

# define binning boundaries
binsaa = np.array([2, 4, 6, 8])
binsbb = np.array([5.1, 5.5, 5.7])
binscc = np.array([12])
binsdd = np.array([110, 133])

# create bin indicies
idaa = np.digitize(aa,binsaa,right=True)
idbb = np.digitize(bb,binsbb,right=True)
idcc = np.digitize(cc,binscc,right=True)
iddd = np.digitize(dd,binsdd,right=True)

# tile some of the indicies so they match the shape of the data to be averaged
idbbt = np.tile(idbb,[1,10])
idcct = np.tile(idcc,[1,10])
idddt = np.tile(iddd,[1,10])

# make empty destination 4 dimensional arrays 
avgxx = np.zeros([5,4,2,3])
cntxx = np.zeros([5,4,2,3])

# use for loops to average original data and place in 4-dim array
for ixa in range(5):
    for ixb in range(4):
        for ixc in range(2):
            for ixd in range(3):
                idz = (idaa == ixa) &  (idbbt == ixb) &  (idcct == ixc) &  (idddt == ixd)
                avgxx[ixa,ixb,ixc,ixd] = np.average(zz[idz])
                cntxx[ixa,ixb,ixc,ixd] = np.sum(idz)

print(avgxx[:,:,:,:])
print(cntxx[:,:,:,:])
```